# Print username and email id in google signin in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase

```
package donet.mychatapp;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SignInButton mGooglebtn;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static final String TAG2 = "FacebookLogin";
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private static final String TAG = "StartActivity";
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
   private FirebaseUser mfirebaseuser;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
 TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        mGooglebtn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.mGooglebtn);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        textView=(TextView)  findViewById(R.id.rough);
        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
// Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();



        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG2, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG2, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG2, "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });


        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "you got an error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        mGooglebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("please wait you are signing in");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.show();

                    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url

                    String name = mfirebaseuser.getDisplayName();
                    String email = mfirebaseuser.getEmail();
                    Uri photoUrl = mfirebaseuser.getPhotoUrl();
                    String uid = mfirebaseuser.getUid();
                  //  register_user(name);
                  //  textView.setText(email);




                signIn();

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();

            textView.setText(personEmail);



            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //  updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }


    public void needaccount(View view) {
        Intent startintent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(startintent);
        finish();
    }

    public void alreadyaccount(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, signinactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }


                    }
                });



        }

    private void register_user( String name) {


        String uid = mfirebaseuser.getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
        HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        userMap.put("name", name);
        userMap.put("status", "Hi there I'm using Diet App");
        userMap.put("image", "default");
        userMap.put("thumb_image", "default");

        databaseReference.setValue(userMap);
    }

    }
```

1. Tell me how to  print username and basic details in google sign in and facebook sign in using firebase in android.
2. All the methods like getdisplayname and get email id are not working.
3. Please send some example or code which can help me.

Comment: "l the methods like getdisplayname and get email id are not working " What exactly do you mean by not working? Returning nulls?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @Rohan Starc  when i am going to print strings using getdisplayname on textview no name printed

Answer (score 0):

Check *Get a user's provider-specific profile information* section

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: all tried but not working bro or may be i am not using it properly  . so please  send me some sample code if you have .

Comment: Would you share the code snippet the code that you say not working?